# openVPN not working on Android 10 in androidstudio when Complie with SDK 29

Tags: openvpn, android-10.0

I download the openvpn project and i build it with my android stdio, and run on my mobile (android Q). everything worked fine i can connect to VPN using this application. then i upgrade this project and compile it with SDK29 and set target vesion to 29 (Gradle). than i run the proj on my mobile and im seeing this error `2020-06-16 18:27:34.473 3094-4456/com.falcon.turbovpn E/OpenVPN: OpenVPNThread Got java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Process.destroy()' on a null object reference`  and unbale to connect to VPN, i tried different things like updating all lib as i think error refer to open VPN lib, but i don't have any idea how to update open vpn properly.
as of my judgement this error is maybe due to as andorid changes is file system in Android Q that how we can read, save and share file. 
Please guide me if any one have any idea. i downloaded the project from here https://drive.google.com/uc?id=18vldMyQib-f3XpjmCYK_TQ4ZMMLTtIw9&export=download

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? I am also facing the same issue but only if I publish release .aab file. It is working if I sideload the apk.

Comment: No!   what I got to know , and yes obviously don't remember all the things very well but what I member I'm writing, the open vpn don't work after sdk 28 as android block the outsource library to interact directly with its system, so now there is some kind of technique involved.
I would prefer to read all the details https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn here and try sample app as well than you should move forward for any work,
also i found this guy giving paid solution 
https://www.fiverr.com/bicky1995/fix-openvpn-not-working-on-android-10

Comment: I fixed the issue by myself, writing here just to help someone else, 
Just add this line in your project's gradle.properties file
`android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false`

.aab file handles the .so files a bit differently that's why VPN was not working in .aab bundle releases.